# Select buttons of list rows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

*There is MCQ type of design I have multiple questions here with each of its answer is "YES", "NO" or "either" I want to select any one of them in each row of the list https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwFfv.png*

what I have done, I took grid list inside List, but i can not manage it , even if i take three button as row instead of grid, its still not working

```
   ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 2,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final _isSelected = _selectedIndexs.contains(index);
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    height: 42,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      controller: questionController,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Question 1",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          borderSide:
                              new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                        ),
                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          borderSide:
                              new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10),
                    child: GridView.count(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        childAspectRatio: 2,
                        children: List.generate(3, (index1) {
                          List<String> choiceList = ["Yes", "No", "Either"];
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedAns = index1;

                                // if (_isSelected) {
                                //   _selectedIndexs.remove(index);
                                // } else {
                                //   _selectedIndexs.add(index);
                                // }
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: (selectedAns == index1)
                                        ? Constants.appfadeColor
                                        : Colors.grey.shade700,
                                    width: 1),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: (selectedAns == index1)
                                    ? Constants.appfadeColor
                                    : Colors.white,
                              ),
                              height: 40,
                              width: 90,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  choiceList[index1],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        })))
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
```

Note -: If i click "yes" its background must get red, if i click "No" then its background get red, but "yes" background must get white , means only one button selection in row

Comment: Where you are setting red color in code? I have seen Constants.appfadeColor. Is it red?

Comment: yes, dont focus on color, what i mean i can select one button at a time for different rows, its same like mcq at last i have to send array of answer selected to backend

Comment: There is another problem. You also have to create a list instead of one varible `selectedAns`.

Comment: any answer u can suggest it must work as mcq

Answer (score -1):

Try implementing ToggleButtons for each row and with that you should be able to solve your issue. Check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html) for more details.

```
ToggleButtons(
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
    Icon(Icons.call),
    Icon(Icons.cake),
  ],
  onPressed: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
    });
  },
  isSelected: isSelected,
),
```